# Will a license check fail if I am in a foreign country?

Tags: applications, drm, localization

I have an app that performs a license check and will not work if a check doesn't succeed within *x* amount of time since the last successful check.  Will this license check fail if I am connected to the Internet in a foreign country?

The app in question is [Final Fantasy III (com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP&hl=en).  However, most other paid apps perform license checks, so this is a question of broader scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually no - however, it's my opinion that this is a rather vague question that can't be accurately answered without knowing the app developer's policy or whether the app is locked to a particular region.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really can't consider this a complete answer, since there isn't enough evidence behind it.  Can you provide personal experience with this issue?

Comment: It's usually media apps like music streaming apps etc that are region locked (although some EA games are too). Your game should run fine so long as it's able to pass the licence check.

Comment: You're right - the application did successfully verify the license through the Wi-Fi at the Hong Kong airport I'm in right now.